# Find $\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^nx^{n+1} \over n + 1} \right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^n \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking for the simplest form of

$$\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^nx^{n+1} \over n + 1} \right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^n \right)$$
We can use the Cauchy product
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i b_{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(-1)^ix^{i+1} \over i + 1}(-1)^{n-i} x^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(-1)^n x^{n+1} \over i + 1}$$
I suspect this can be written down in a trigonometric form involving the sine or cosine. How can I get from this expression to the trigonometric form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^{n}  =\frac1{1+x},\quad |x|<1,
$$ and that
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^nx^{n+1} \over n + 1} =\ln(1+x),\quad |x|<1,
$$ then the *simplest form* of 
$$
\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^nx^{n+1} \over n + 1} \right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^n \right)
$$ could just be

> $$
> \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x},\quad |x|<1.
> $$

Comment: Is there a way to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^nx^{n+1} \over n + 1} = \ln{(1+x)}$ without the use of integrals?

Comment: @Zelazny I think it's difficult to elude $\left( \ln (1+x)\right)'=\frac1{1+x}.$

Comment: @Zelazny That gets back to the question "What is your definition of ln?" It's often defined as the appropriate integral, which is going to make it tough to avoid. Even if you define it as the inverse of $e^x$, $e^x$ will often be defined as the function $f(x)$ such that $df/dx=f$ and $f(0)=1$...

Comment: @Zelazny A possible route. Using the binomial theorem one may prove that $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^nx^{n+1} \over n + 1}$, $0\le x\le1$,  satisfies $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$, $f(0)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous over $[0,1]$, one may prove that $f$ is in fact $\log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Remember that for $\;|x|<1\;$

$$\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n\implies\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the various comments about the overall sum, it's worth noting that there's a reasonable 'simplest form' for the coefficients as well.  Factor out the terms $x^{n+1}$ and note that you're looking at a sum of the form $a_{n+1}=(-1)^n\sum_{i=0}^n\frac1{i+1}$, where I've labeled this as $a_{n+1}$ since it's the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in the product series. By reindexing the sum and then making the substitution $n+1\mapsto n$, this is the same as $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$, which should be a familiar-looking series.